# Maven Unrecognised Tag: 'executions'

Tags: maven, tags, pom.xml, execution

The problem is simple. I added `<executions></executions>` tag in my pom.xml, however I got the below error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: MyProject
POM Location: MyPOM

Reason: Parse error reading POM. Reason: Unrecognised tag: 'executions' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>  \t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    <executions>... @2014:23)
for project MyProject
```

May it be caused by the version of Maven that I use? My Maven version is 2.1.0. I couldn't find when "executions" tag have been implemented. Without the "executions" tag everything is OK and I tried a few examples of code from the web but didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: First why have you added them and please show your full pom file? And why in havens name do you use an such archaic Maven version ? Please see [EoL of Maven 2.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: the `<executions>` tag is used to configure the behavior of plugins. They belong in a specific place in your POM file. Like the previous person said, show the full POM file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
   <executions> tag must be within the <build> </build> section
```

if your plugin not inside the main build section , move it there.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved the problem by inserting `<extensions>true</extensions>` before `<executions>` tag.
The structure just as

```
.......    
</plugin>
     <plugin>
       <extensions>true</extensions>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase></phase>
           <goals>
             <goal></goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>    
   </plugins>   
</build>
```